# Any chance to limit users available for selection in PeopleEditor control to users from one web?

Tags: people-picker

I have site collection with many subwebs. There is a lot of usergroups in site collection - every subweb has it's own members, visitors and owners associated. I need to use a PeopleEditor control, but I would need to limit available users/groups to only those, who have some rights at given web.
Is there any option for that? I'm not able to find anything working. 
Many thanks
Filip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this resolve your problem , but you can create a group dedicated to this purpose. so if a user can be selected, you add it to this group. and you set this group as a source to the people picker.

Otherwise you have to develop  a custom field that inherit from people picker, and implement a mechanism that let you manage the source of the people picker.

Comment: Thanks, I've thought that it's so, but wanted to be sure, that I'm not missing some out-of-the-box option.